Automatic sort when the data is entered into the other sheet and imported via the formula
I am having trouble trying to write a script that will auto sort a dataset when a value is changed in one of the columns. The values are derived from formulas that draw their data from another sheet in the workbook.
I have been successful in getting the sheet to update when I manually update data using onEdit but I cannot seem to get it to work when the data is entered into the other sheet and imported via the formula.

Although, unfortunately, I cannot know your actual situation, about but I cannot seem to get it to work when the data is entered into the other sheet and imported via the formula., is this post useful for your situation? https://medium.com/google-cloud/workaround-detecting-change-of-importrange-using-onedit-trigger-with-google-apps-script-92748e25df60

you can set up a trigger

The easiest solution is to set the trigger on the data entry spreadsheet.
